# asp.net c# - combine / format a date and time from separate sources

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I'm parsing an XML file from an external source, and I have 2 attributes which contain the date and time respectively.  I'm looking for the best way to get these into a format I can parse as a date so I can do things with it, but at the moment I'm just getting errors or no results with the methods I've tried.

The date is in the format "20111215" - which is yyyymmdd as it's UK based.
The time is formatted as "1417+0000" which I presume is the time plus offset from GMT?

Basically I need to get these into UK time.  I've tried using DateTime.Parse on the separate parts but both give an error as not valid format.  Tried String.Format on the date part but that didn't change it at all.  I presume I need to combine the 2 before parsing but I'm not sure if I need to do anything else with it to make it acceptable.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you tried [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)?

Comment: thanks everyone for the help - I'd never seen ParseExact before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DateTimeOffset to incorporate the timezone into the DateTime.

```
        string date = "20111215";
        string time = "1417+0500";

        string dateAndTime = date + time;

        string format = "yyyyMMddHHmmzzz";

        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        DateTimeOffset t = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateAndTime, format, provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate the fields together, you can then use `DateTime.TryParseExact` in order to parse them into a `DateTime`.

```
string input = string.Format("{0} {1}", dateString, timeString);
DateTime parsed;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(input, 
                          "yyyyMMdd HHmmK", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                          DateTimeStyles.None, 
                          out parsed))
{
  // parsed OK, use the parsed variable
}
```

Comment: @BasB - [The "K" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#KSpecifier) - for Time zone information.

Comment: What is K in "HHmmK" and where you setting offset?

Comment: @AlexDn - See the link in my previous comment to Bas B. That's where the offset it set.

Comment: @Oded, so if i understand correctly, K will return time with current timezone? If it's right, so it will ignore the timezone from the original data?

Comment: @AlexDn - "K" in the format string stands for the timezone specified. With a timezone of `+0000`, nothing happens. With a `+0500` you will get the time specified + 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "20111215";
string time = "1417+0000";
string dateString = date + time;;
string format = "yyyyMMddHHmmK"; 
// or something similar, I'm not sure about the timezone

DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, 
                                      format, 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work (i didn't test it):

```
string dateString = "20111215";
string timeString = "1417+0000";
int year = int.Parse(dateString.Substring(0,4));
int month = int.Parse(dateString.Substring(4,2));
int day = int.Parse(dateString.Substring(6,2));

int hour = int.Parse(dateString.Substring(0,2));
int mins = int.Parse(dateString.Substring(2,2));

DateTime d = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, mins, 0);
```

Comment: In order to set time offset, use d.AddHours([parse time string the same way as for hour and minutes, just use correct indexes]); I assume "+" in time string may be "-" when representing GMT -.